# Handling key strokes when window not focused/active

Tags: winapi, window, focus, keystroke, accelerator

I need to handle keys combination (`CTRL+SHIFT+UP`) in WinAPI even if window is not focused/active.

How can I do this (if possible, I'd prefer solution without using [WinApi Hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644960%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))?

Comment: Use RegisterHotKey().

Comment: What if I wanted to use Ctrl+Shift+Up in another application?, e.g. select previous paragaraph in Word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to register a "system-wide" hot key with [RegisterHotKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. It works even if your application is minimized, not focused, or hidden.

```
RegisterHotKey(hWnd, KEY_ID, MOD_CONTROL | MOD_SHIFT, VK_UP);
// check for errors, the function will fail if the hot key is already registered
```

`hWnd` is the handle of the window that will receive WM_HOTKEY message. `KEY_ID` is the identifier for the hot key. `MOD_CONTROL | MOD_SHIFT` for both Ctrl+Shift. `VK_UP` for the Up arrow key.

Second, you need to handle the WM_HOTKEY message in your window procedure.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (uMsg) {
        ...
        WM_HOTKEY:
        // handle the hot key here
        ...
    }
}
```

If your application does not have a window and `hWnd` is NULL, then you need to handle the WM_HOTKEY in your message loop.

```
MSG msg = {0};
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) != 0)
{
    if (msg.message == WM_HOTKEY) {
        // handle the hot key here
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer, even better that you included the need to check for errors. +1